# How to extend SentenceDetector with custom splitting character in OpenNLP?

Tags: java, nlp, opennlp

I am trying to add custom feature in sentence Detector Model (OpenNLP). By default it detects based on these character ., ? !. I want to add a new character, so that my model will detect based on that.

Can you suggest me how to implement that?

Answer (score 2):

For [OpenNLP 1.6.0](https://opennlp.apache.org/announcement/release-160.html) you can make use of the `SentenceDetectorFactory`. It's constructor allows you to inject custom end of sentence (eos) characters (see [JavaDoc](http://opennlp.apache.org/documentation/1.6.0/apidocs/opennlp-tools/opennlp/tools/sentdetect/SentenceDetectorFactory.html)):

> SentenceDetectorFactory(String languageCode, boolean useTokenEnd, Dictionary abbreviationDictionary, char[] eosCharacters)

In combination with `SentenceDetectorME` we have this hint in the corresponding [JavaDoc](http://opennlp.apache.org/documentation/1.6.0/apidocs/opennlp-tools/opennlp/tools/sentdetect/SentenceDetectorME.html):

> public SentenceDetectorME(SentenceModel model,
>                     Factory factory)
>
> *Deprecated*. Use a SentenceDetectorFactory to extend SentenceDetector functionality.

So you could implement your *own* implementation of `SentenceDetector` by extending `SentenceDetectorME` with an exchanged instance of your custom `SentenceDetectorFactory` which then uses other chars to detect sentence endings.

Hope it helps.